# Unable to reach all hosts behind OpenVPN via Netgear R7000 running FreshTomato

Tags: networking, router, openvpn

I have OpenVPN running on an Netgear R7000 via FreshTomato firmware. I am able to connect remotely to the VPN just fine. However, I cannot ping all the hosts behind the VPN. For instance, the remote LAN Subnet is 10.0.1.X. I can ping/connect to 10.0.1.1 (the Router), 10.0.1.205 (a Windows System) but I cannot ping/connect to 10.0.1.201. I have the following in my config which I thought should allow access to all hosts:

push "route 10.0.1.0 255.255.255.0"

I tested disabling the Firewall on 10.0.1.201, no joy there.

I can ssh to the router (10.0.1.1) and ping all hosts behind the VPN. However, from the client connected to the VPN (either a MAC or Windows box), I can only ping/connect to 10.0.1.1 and 10.0.1.205, I cant connect to any other hosts behind the VPN. What is even more perplexing, other clients that connect the VPN remotely can connect to other hosts such as 10.0.1.42, which I am unable to connect to. I tried playing with iptables in the router, but chickened out as I am not an iptables expert.

I cant help but feel that I am missing something very obvious/stupid on my part. I am also hesitant to make any major changes for fear of breaking access altogether.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Please post your OpenVPN server and client configs within code boxes, as well as the client and server logs with verbosity set to `4` on the server, `5` on the client _(once done, restart the server and reconnect with the client, try to reach a host behind the router, then post the logs)_ as without these, no one can answer this question.